# Compatibilities Ubuntu-ROS-ROSI

Tags: ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any place where to find the compatibilities between the different UBUNTU-ROS-ROSI releases?
because I cant find it in all the different ros-wiki's

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242504/compatibilities-ubuntu-ros-rosi/) by [JoostW](https://answers.ros.org/users/27844/joostw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only packages in ROS-Industrial released into Jade at this moment are those in [industrial_core](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_core). Those packages can be installed using `apt-get` (at least on Ubuntu).

As to the rest of ROS-Industrial: that has not been released, but as the differences between Indigo and Jade are relatively minor, most -- if not all -- packages should be usable under Jade. The only drawback is that you'd need to build them from source.

> Is there any place where to find the compatibilities between the different UBUNTU-ROS-ROSI releases?

If with "compatibilities" you mean: into which ROS releases ROS-Industrial packeges have been released, then I'm afraid there is (currently) not a single location that displays that information.

You can however find out in multiple places if a package is released for a specific platform and ROS release:

1. look at the green 'badges' at the top of the wiki pages for the package: switch to the ROS release that you are interested in (using the version rocker at the top of the page), and look for a `✔ Released` badge. If you can't find that, or the package doesn't have a button in the rocker for the ROS release you are interested in, then it's safe to assume it hasn't been released.
2. use any of the available *release status* pages, such as [ROS Jade - release status](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_jade_default.html) for Jade. Those pages can be filtered: [here](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_jade_default.html?q=industrial) is a query for `industrial` in Jade. See [here](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/) for all status pages. If a package is not listed on that page, it's safe to assume it hasn't been released.

> because I cant find it in all the different ros-wiki's

(slightly pedantic) but there is only a single "ROS wiki", the one at `wiki.ros.org`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0